# Youtube iframe embed - play video only after buffering is complete

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, preload

Is there a way to show an animated gif(ajaxload.info) while the youtube video is still buffering and play it only when buffering is fully complete?

What I need to do is show an animation while the video is buffering. Then remove the animated image and show & play the video box when buffering is complete.

Right now I am using a fake preloader for 5 seconds using setTimeout but that's not the proper way of doing it.

Requesting help from all gurus.

Thanks in advance for your kind help & advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can check here for events http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html.